# Как отлаживать скрипты в MODX REVO 2.5

Tags: php, modx

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получать сообщения об ошибках в консоли(есть такой пакет, который позволяет выполнять php-скрипты). например есть код:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!$parent_resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
  'parent' => 3,
  'published' => 1
))){ return; };

$output = '';

foreach ($parent_resources as $parent_resource) {
  $parent_resource_id = $parent_resource->get('id');

  $output .= $parent_resource_id;

  $child_resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
    'parent' => $parent_resource_id,
    'published' => 1
  ));



};
```

в нём ошибка потому что в результате на экран ничего не выводится. но мне хотелось бы получить хоть какие-то сообщения

Как видите, я в начале скрипта включил error_reporting и ini_set. Так же в .htaccess я прописал:

```
php_flag display_errors On
php_value error_reporting "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE"
```

Но это не помогает

ps:
Пожалуйста не подсказывайте как исправить приведённый скрипт. Вопрос не в том как исправить, вопрос в том как в принципе получать сообщения об ошибках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два типа ошибок в модиксе:

1. Ошибки php - такие можно смотреть в логах апача.
2. Ошибки модикса(выведенные через $modx->log), которые можно смотреть в журнале ошибок.

Определись для начала какой тип ошибок ты хочешь смотреть, после отправляйся смотреть логи.

Answer (score 1):

Журнал ошибок modx находится в  `modx_core/cache/logs/error.log`

Его можно посмотреть скачав по ftp, либо через ssh.

Так же доступ к журналу ошибок можно получить через панель администрирования modx, выбрав в меню: Управление -> Отчёты -> Журнал ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Для записи отладочной информации в журнал ошибок MODx из сниппета, используйте следующий код.

```
$err = print_r(data, 1); 
$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'debug message: '.$err);
```

Журнал ошибок доступен из меню Управление -> Отчёты -> Журнал ошибок

Comment: `print_r(data)` выводит информацию в поток, а вот `print_r(data,1)` возвратит строку

Comment: Vasis, Все верно!